# Google chrome does not open in ubuntu 22.04 after some updates

Tags: google-chrome

Today, when I was using google chrome, I updated it with apt-get. After the update, my ubuntu screen went black and I restarted my laptop. Since there, chrome does not open. I also tried:

1. Removing the `/.config/google-chrome` directories: `rm -rf ~/.config/google-chrome*`
2. Removing the `share/applications/chrome-*` directories: `rm /home/emadhelmi/.local/share/applications/chrome-*`
3. Editing the exec command from the `.desktop` file and add `--v=1` to the command.
4. Purging the package and re-install it via the latest `.deb` package.
   None of the above solutions work!

My Chrome version is `Google Chrome 115.0.5790.110` and my Ubuntu version is `Ubuntu 22.04.2 LTS` and I'm using `X.Org server` as my additional driver.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

google-chrom-stable 120 has the problem but google-chrome-beta 121 runs fine

Comment: If you could add a link providing some information about it, it would be some more helpful.

Answer (score 0):

I've searched nearly all forums and other questions on stackoverflow but none of them works.
The only solution that worked for me was to set the default grub entry not to be any `*-Nvidia-lowlatency`